# User 'www-data' is sometimes 'forgetting' its groups (but only sometimes)

Tags: php, apache, unix, file-permissions

I am trying to set up a sandboxed area in /var/sandbox that some php code run through the website should be allowed to change. I've set it up so that the sandbox folder has 775 permissions and is assigned to the group 'sandbox-users', then added the group 'sandbox-users' to the 'www-data' user profile so that it can be edited when run through Apache.

However, the php script I'm running only works some of the time, and it seems that this is because sometimes 'www-data' forgets that it is part of the 'sandbox-users' group. I have the following line in my php code:

```
echo shell_exec('whoami') . " | " . shell_exec('whoami | groups') . "<br>";
```

The times that the script works, I (appropriately) get the output:

```
www-data | www-data sandbox-users
```

When it doesn't work, I just get back:

```
www-data | www-data
```

There doesn't seem to be any pattern to when the script works and when it doesn't - it switches back and forth if given time.

Is there any reason that www-data would drop its groups? And is there any way to prevent this?

EDIT: To add another interesting wrinkle to this, if I go to the terminal and run 'groups www-data', it tells me that www-data is in the sandbox-users group always, including in the few seconds between two failed script runs that give me the second output (no sandbox-users group) listed above.

Comment: To be certain it is not a restart problem, have you been restarting apache? Without a restart some of the apache subprocess may be olders than others.

Answer (score 0):

@regilero was spot on - the web server had not been restarted and some of the apache processes were legacies from before the www-data group was changed. So the randomness was based on whether the webpage was served from a newer or older process. Restarting these processes solved this issue. Always remember the first rule of IT: restart and see if that fixes it!